# How do I delegate a string without redefining it , in another class?

Tags: android

I am pretty new to android and trying to figure out delegation. To explain the same.
I have a search box for which I am defining a search text string as follows in class FragmentA:

```
protected EditText mSearchView;
```

Now, I have another class FragmentB extends Fragment A, which is using the same in a method as follows:

```
private void displayQuotes(final String searchAutoSuggestTitle, final String searchAutoSuggestSubTitle, final String searchAutoSuggestSymbol) {
        killLastSearchAutoSuggestTask();

        String text = mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase() + " " + mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

        if(searchAutoSuggestSymbol.toLowerCase().contains(mSearchView.getText().toString().toLowerCase())){
        QuotesFragmentWebView.newInstanceForSearch(getFragmentManager(), searchAutoSuggestSymbol, null);
        }
        else if(!searchAutoSuggestSymbol.toLowerCase().contains(text)){//mSearchView.getText().toString()))&&""&&(searchAutoSuggestSymbol.contains(mSearchView.getText().toString()))){
            AnswersWebViewFragment.newInstanceForSearch(getFragmentManager(), searchAutoSuggestSymbol, null);

        } else {

        }
        hideSearchView();
    }
```

Now, the values are retrieved for mSearchView text for the text typed in. Now I have another class Fragment C which extends Fragment implements Onclicklistener,mainactivity, and no specific classes. I have a URL in there which I am defining as :

```
public final static String search_1_result = "https://mobile13.cp.com/fwd/results/answers/service/v1/?q="+mSearchView.getText().toString()+"%20revenue&ui.theme=novadark&uuid=PADACT-002";
```

But, I wonder how do I make it recognize the mSearchView.getText().toString() value(including recognizing mSearchView which it is throwing as an error,since its not defined in that specific class) . Also how do I carry on the typed value in Fragment B for the search, to be used in the url given above?

Thanks!
brian

Comment: you want 'text' string value from fragmentB in fragmentC ?

Comment: yea , I am trying to get mSearchView which is defined in Fragment A and retrieved in Fragment B to be used in Fragment C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this thread :
[How do I use the parameter defined in another class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20107525/how-do-i-use-the-parameter-defined-in-another-class/20107613?noredirect=1#20107613)
I had a similar issue , 
You just need to define a function say

```
    -public fragment(or your class can be your view class) extends whatever{
        -public void thisfunction(){
        //code to add
        }

}
```

call that in the class you require and define the functionality in the main class from which you wish to delegate and call it inside the function referring to the fragment class.(exactly the same as in the class reference I gave you),don't forget to get the required listeners with implements functionality, in the example onrawerclosedlistener.