# How do I use the parameter defined in another class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-navigation

I am using a navigation drawer in my main activity defined as

```
private DrawerLayout drawerlayout;
```

I am using it in main activity to open and close my nav fragment, but there are 3 specific buttons in nav fragment class where I would like to use the nav fragment functionality `drawerlayout.closedrawer(r.id.drawer)`
But everytime I define it again in nav fragment class and try to add it in the onclick for these buttons, upon clicking the buttons, the app crashes with a nullpointer exception.How do I go about the same?

Thanks!
Here's the sample code from my app:
public class navfragment extends fragment {

```
public interface OnCloseDrawerListener
      {
         void onCloseDrawer();
      }
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_logout:

                final DialogFragment dialog = new LogoutCancelSignoutDialogFragment(mLogoutListener);
                dialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), AbsBaseaActivity.TAG_LOGOUT_DIALOG);
                BangoHelper.eventLogout();
                ((OnCloseDrawerListener)getActivity()).onCloseDrawer();
                break;
}
}
```

In my class MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AbsBaseaActivity implements OnBackStackChangedListener {
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        //----------Code for Navigation Drawer setup
        // 2. App Icon 
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        // 2.1 create ActionBarDrawerToggle
                 actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
                            R.drawable.arrow_up, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){

                        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
                        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                           // getActionBar().setTitle(NavigationPanelFragment.activeFragmentTitle);
                           // invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                        }

                        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
                        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                         //   getActionBar().setTitle(NavigationPanelFragment.activeFragmentTitle);
                          //  invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
                        }
                    };


                // 2.2 Set actionBarDrawerToggle as the DrawerListener
                drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

}
public  void onCloseDrawer()
       {
         drawerLayout.closeDrawer(R.id.drawer);
       }
    Even after modifying the code as per the given suggestion it crashes when I click on the button defined onclick for the fragment class, any clue?
```

Comment: Show some code how you access the Drawer from your Fragment.

Comment: you need to call back to the activity from the fragment and access the drawerLayout there

Comment: added the code ,can you guys check it out and lemme know if you have any clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a callback from your fragment to your activity to close the drawer..

Ex.

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment
{

  public void onClick(View v)
  {
    ((OnCloseDrawerListener)getActivity()).onCloseDrawer();
  }

  public interface OnCloseDrawerListener
  {
     void onCloseDrawer();
  }
}
```

Then in your activity you would need to implement this interface

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnCloseDrawerListener
{
   @Override
   public  void onCloseDrawer()
   {
        // add whatever code you need to close the drawer
   }

}
```

Obviously you can name this interface something that more accurately represents your needs and pass it whatever arguments you require

Comment: I added the code including the code from your suggestion and it still crashes, can you check it out and lemme know what I am doing wrong? thanks!

Comment: @JusticeBauer You didn't actually include the "implements" portion in your class declaration. add ", OnCloseDrawerListener" after "implements OnBackStackChangedListener" in your activity.

Comment: you sir, are a genius, that worked thanks! +25 for you. Also, do you happen to have any idea about this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20058491/how-do-i-call-2-consecutive-items-in-a-list-in-a-table-form-next-to-each-other/20123157?noredirect=1#comment29992686_20123157